# Statement is not valid in a namespace?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a small VB.net program.  In the Declarations section of the main form, I have the following line of code:

```
 Private _layoutManager as LayoutManager = LayoutManager.Instance()
```

When I enter this, I get the error message:

```
Statement is not valid in a namespace
```

Even entering something as simple as

```
Private Total as integer
```

gives me the same error.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your entire code would be nice. Though I suspect you did not put your statement in a `Class`, `Method`, `Property`, or other container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not valid:

```
Private Total as Integer

Public Class Form1

'
'
'
'

End Class
```

This is:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Total as Integer

    '
    '
    '
    '

End Class
```